# Redis enter or newline in SET

Tags: redis, newline, enter

How to SET a key in Redis with enter|new line, for example

```
SET newkey "Text begins here
and ends here on the new line"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following (e.g. with Python):

```
In [1]: import redis

In [2]: r = redis.Redis()

In [3]: r.set('newkey', 'Text begins here\x0a\x0dand ends here on the new line')
Out[3]: True

In [4]: print r.get('newkey')
Text begins here
and ends here on the new line
```